Driving Piezo Using Unfiltered Sine Wave PWM

Can piezoelectric components like Langevin transducers be driven using unfiltered near sine wave PWM? If so, what are the upsides / downsides? Where can I learn more?
As an example, I'm attaching ~1MHz PWM and a corresponding 20kHz sine wave.

It's not a very good idea unless you add sufficient series inductance. The reason is that piezoelectric components (in general) have a capacitive reactance and, if applied with a square voltage waveform, the peak currents can be tens of amps and destroy driving circuits.
Adding sufficient series inductance and operating above the resonant frequency will ensure that the driving circuit sees a net inductive reactance. A net inductive reactance will not consume huge peaks of current of course.
However, if the effective series resistance (ESR) of the piezoelectric component is high-enough then you should be OK without an inductor but, given you haven't linked a specific data sheet I can only generalize.

Thanks for the answer! Here's an example transducer, I don't think it has high enough ESR though https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/1e5fcf252d285ac3-A8068245-A793-9BC7-F4B6E14ED5C2E68F/PKT40A-SpecSheet.pdf

@beardeadclown 404 page not found error

What about this link https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PKT40A

@beardeadclown that device should be OK but, you ought to run the circuit slightly above resonance to ensure it's always in the inductive region but, it all depends on how decent your driver is. See the impedance response graph on page 2 and note that between 20 kHz and 21.375 kHz the response is inductive. The impedance goes from below 1 ohm to nearly 5 ohms in this region. Drive voltage and impedance determine current and, your driver has to supply this without burning.

I'm actually a little bit confused about the drive voltage on that one, because the data sheet says that the power is 700W, so at 21kHz we'll have 3 ohm impedance, hence 45 volts & 15 amps, but according to the datasheet that power is measured at 3kV and can be driven with voltages up to 5kV, so not sure what the drivers output waveform should look like

@beardeadclown I suspect that we can never know that without Thorlabs revealing what they mean. It does say that the voltage is 3 kV instantaneous and, you might get this during a transient but I can't see how you'll get this voltage level during normal continuous operation. Maybe if you pulse the device, the average power is 700 watts but, the instantaneous power is massive (as per sonar systems)? Or maybe they mean you should pulse it and ensure the pulse width keeps the instantaneous power below 700 watts? I'm favouring the latter reason.

Could it be that the amplitude is ~45 volts, but it's biased at around 3000?

@beardeadclown I doubt it but, we are now into asking Thorlabs that question.
